# One of the roots obtained by Reduce for a complex polynomial is wrong

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to find the roots of a complex polynomial using `Reduce` but one of these roots is wrong. Here is the code:

```
A = {2 + 3 I, -1, -3 - 7 I, 5, 7 + 3 I, 1 + I, 4 + 2 I, -5 I, -7, I, 
2 + 8 I, 2, -7, 8 - 2 I, 6, 5 + 4 I, 2, 3, -1 + I, -6 I};
a[n_] := A[[n + 1]];
P[z_, n_] := Sum[a[i] z^i, {i, 0, n - 1}] + z^n

roots = Reduce[P[z, 20] == 0, z, WorkingPrecision -> 1000] // N;
Column[Table[Abs[P[roots[[i, 2]], 20]], {i, 1, 20}]]
5.17283*10^-14
5.00958*10^-15
7.22453*10^-16
4.59403*10^-15
1.0258*10^-14
4.59215*10^-16
1.03316*10^-14
2.42523*10^-13
0.760345
3.31691*10^-16
2.30662*10^-14
9.42139*10^-14
2.86429*10^-14
2.30469*10^-15
1.96808*10^-16
2.88871*10^-15
5.17893*10^-15
6.36412*10^-15
9.94254*10^-15
1.65878*10^-13
```

Comment: Try `roots = Reduce[P[z, 20] == 0, z] // N[#, 1000] &;` instead.

Comment: I agree with @AccidentalFourierTransform that this is a numerical precision issue, not a polynomial root-finding issue. Evaluating high-degree polynomials is difficult because of huge cancellation effects.

Comment: @ AccidentalFourierTransform, It gives the same root (root#9) in my code but when substituting in `Abs[P[roots,20]]` it gives zeros without numbers?!! How can I show  numbers for `Abs[P[roots,20]]` ?

Comment: @ AccidentalFourierTransform, using your method the 9th root still gives a magnitude difference of order 10^12 compared with rest of the roots?